# Sonatype Nexus: "invalid authentication ticket" on password change

Tags: nexus

I'm trying to change the admin password. I get this error:
invalid authentication ticket

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a known issue: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10252

You need just to change your password within 15 seconds after entering current password.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hack(ethical) and hence alternate but longer way to do this :-)

Steps:-

1. **Create a new admin user**(previously logged in using admin default credentials) - different user name, etc, etc
2. Now **login using new(admin) user** that you created in step 1.
3. **Delete** the **previous admin** user (the default one)
4. Again **create a new admin user** using new credentials
5. **Login using admin user** that you just created, and problemo solved :-)

Comment: Actually, you don't even have to delete the admin user.  Once you have logged in as the new user you can simply change the password for the original admin account.

Comment: Yes, for few specific versions this is a work around, where changing password is not possible due unknown reason

Answer (score 0):

It looked like i was changing the password and something else at the same time. I had to save the profile and then proceed with the password change.